# C++: Copying pointer to const object into non-const object pointer

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, constants

In my custom class, I'm getting an error when declaring the input variable pointer as constant and copying it into a non-constant member variable pointer.

The error I get is:

> Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'Position *' with an
> lvalue of type 'const Position *'

Why does this happen? And why is this not consistent with the other member variable (`_attack`)? It is only copying the value of the pointer (address) the same way it's copying the value of the int (`_attack`).

```cpp
class Creature
{
private:
  int _attack;
  Position* _position;
public:
  Creature(const int attack, const Position* position)
      : _attack{attack}, _position{position} // ERROR: Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'Position *' with an lvalue of type 'const Position *'
  {}
};
```

Comment: `position` is a pointer to a constant `Position`. The pointer itself is not constant

Comment: It is consistent. `_attack` gets a copy of `attack`, and `_position` gets a copy of `position`. However, `position` is a pointer-to-const object, and `_position` is not.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys. It's a delicate but important distinction, I must have confused it with Position* const (constant pointer to a Position)

Comment: doesnt always help with c++ code, but for const pointer vs pointer to const it does: https://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter does not refer to anything outside of the constructor scope as it is just a copy. The const in that case is only saying that your constructor itself is not allowed to change the value of `attack`.

The second parameter is a pointer to a `const Position`. If you could assign that to a non-const `Position*`, you could then mutate that position through the non-const pointer. If this was allowed, there would be no way for someone to create an instance of your class if they have a Position pointer they did not want mutated by your constructor.

Note that you can make the second parameter behave the same as the first by changing it to `Position* const position`. This makes the pointer const but not the object it is pointing to.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const?rq=1) related question.

Comment: Thank you Dean. To be consistent to my function declaration, and making the input arguments unchangeable would that mean I have to declare it with "Position* const position" then?

Comment: @MichelHeusser Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers have two "types" of `const`.  They are

```
const T * pointer_name
```

and

```
T * const pointer_name
```

which can also be combined to the third and final form of

```
const T * const pointer_name
```

With the first one, you are making a pointer to a `const T`.  This is what you have in  constructor.  This goes against the type of `_position`, which is `T *`, or more to the point, a pointer to a non-const `T`.  This is why you are getting an error.  You can't assign to a pointer to non-const `T` the value of a pointer to a `const T`.

With the second form, your code could compile as now you don't have a pointer to a `const T`, but instead you have a `const` pointer to a `T`.  Both pointer point to a non-const thing, so it's okay to assign one to the other

This is the same thing that is happening with `attack`.  While it may be const, you can still copy it's value and place it into another object.

The last form is a `const` pointer to a `const T`, and wouldn't work here again for the same reason as why the first from doesn't work.

---

This also kind of gets into the east-coast vs west-coast const-style.  With west-coast style above, sometimes it's not so easy to understand the type.  Insteasd, you can use east-coast style like

```
T const * pointer_name
T * const pointer_name
T const * const pointer_name
```

and now they all read from right to left exactly what the type is.

Comment: Thank you Nathan!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the `attack` parameter to your constructor (declared as `const`), you are **copying** the value given to your member variable (`_attack`), which is *not* `const`; however, subsequent modification of that member variable will not change the value of the passed parameter, so you aren't "breaking the promise you made."

However, in the case of the `position` parameter, things are very different: the `const` qualifier here states that it points to an object that cannot be modified; but, if you were to copy that pointer's value (i.e. the address) to the non-const member variable, then you would be allowing modification of the referenced object. So, the compiler is (correctly) telling you can't do that.

If what you *actually* want is to pass a *pointer* that is an immutable address, but to an object that *can* be changed, then you need to move the `const` keyword in the constructor's parameters:

```cpp
    Creature(const int attack,  Position* const position) // POINTER is const, POINTEE is not!
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian!